# Android App in Developer Console ist not compatibel with any device

Tags: android, google-play

I got my Google Play Developer Account yesterday. I uploaded my first app, but it isn't compatibel with any device. It always says 0. I think there is something wrong with my Android Manifest.

Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android:hardware.Camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android:hardware.Parameters" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />




<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.arved95.material_torch.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.arved95.material_torch.ButtonScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_button_screen" >
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.arved95.material_torch.WidgetProvider" android:label="MaterialTorch Widget">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />

    </receiver>

</application>
```

If someone knows how to fix that, it would be really nice.

Thx

Comment: You should show whole Manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by adding adding required="false".

```
<uses-feature android:name="android:hardware.Camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android:hardware.Parameters" />
```

to

```
<uses-feature android:name="android:hardware.Camera" required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android:hardware.Parameters" required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Blind guess, you lack

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

in your manifest (must be outside `<application>` block).